# Where is the old OneDrive SDK app registration dashboard

Tags: android, onedrive

I have an old app that still runs using the old OneDrive SDK for Android. It is still functional, but I have a hard time finding the web dashboard where the app is registered.

I can only find the Azure Graph API, but my old app is not listed there.

Thanks.